# Deleted Schema Migration Ruby on Rails sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

So I was stupid and deleted all the rows in the schema_migration of my sqlite3 database. How do I fix this? Did I destroy my whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you delete db\schema.rb or db\migrate files too?

In the first case you can try move db file to other location and execute:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you removed schema.rb and migration files you can execute

```
rails generate migration
```

and recreate migration manually.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify, I edited my development.sqlite3 file using the SQLite Database Browser and deleted everything in the Schema Migrations table.

Comment: Just remove sqlite database file and launch 'rake db:migrate'. It recreate database.

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't need to run `rake db:migrate` again you'll be fine. Otherwise you'll run into problems.

I probably should do this in Ruby, but i'm more familiar with Perl - so here's a quick script that'll help you resurect the schema_migrations table

```
!#/usr/bin/perl

opendir(DH, 'path/to/rails/app/db/migrate');

while($filename = readdir(DH))
{
    next unless $filename =~ /\.rb$/;
    @parts = split("_", $filename);
    print "INSERT INTO schema_migration VALUES (" . $parts[0] . ");\n";
}
```

running the script will give you a series of insert statements that'll then be able to copy and paste into the sqllite command line tool

Answer (score 0):

or you can just kill the DB and restart

```
rake db:drop; rake db:migrate; rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: Multiple tasks can be passed to rake: `rake db:drop db:migrate db:test:prepare`